# No login form in phpMyAdmin welcome page

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

I've installed phpMyAdmin along side apache 2.4 and php 5.6, without any trouble except when I hit phpMyAdmin page with the logo and login form, the form is not diaplayed, not even in the html source code and no error displayed (php error, console or network), I modified the phpMyAdmin settings :

```
/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
```

Without any success, the only things that pop up is this error in the error-php.log :

```
[09-Apr-2016 16:29:10 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class       'PMA\libraries\PMA_Message' not found in D:\jean-philippe\Documents\www\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Message.php on line 586
```

Could this be the root of the problem ?

Thanks for yours further responses.

[phpMyAdmin welcome page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsQG3.png)

[phpMyAdmin seeings and php error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7nXp.png)

Comment: Ps: I'm running on windows 10

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Is this a new install or an upgrade?